# SQL new variable using multiple conditions (count of occurrences in 6 month look-back period using timestamp for each unique ID)

Tags: sql, datetime, conditional-statements, case

I am trying to achieve the following:
[Attached is what my data looks like.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/NJXn5.png)
I want to create 2 new variables which counts the number of times 'Target' (variable 1) and 'Competitor' appears (variable 2), within the last 6 months of a given date_of_prescription. This would be done for every unique D_PRESCRIBER_ID.

So for example:
For ID: 1003000902 prescribing on 2020-03-18 date, the COMPETITOR drug. When you look at the rows before that, you can see that within 6 months prior to the 2020-03-18 date, there are 2 Target drugs prescribed and 0 competitor drugs prescribed. So my variable values will be: 2 (variable 1) and 0 (variable 2)

My data is much larger than what the screenshot looks like. It has more variables and 1000's of unique D_PRESCRIBER_IDs. Each row is not a unique ID, there are duplicates in the data for various date_of_prescription timestamps. These variables need to be created in my select statements in order to keep the rest of the data the same.

Any help here would be awesome. Thanks!

Comment: A [mcve] is a great start when asking for SQL assistance. Note that most people here want sample data and expected result as properly formatted text (no images, no links.)

Comment: Which dbms are you using? (When it comes to date/time, many products are far from ANSI SQL compliant.)

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Comment: MySQL @jarlh I'm coding in snowflake.